# passing a object[] to a params object[] not working

Tags: c#, object, casting, parameters

I've read the topic about passing an object[] to a params object[] but I don't know why it's not working with me.

I have these too functions in a class:

```
...
    private void CallbackEvent(object source, CallbackEvetArgs e) { // Some event with e.Data as string
    ...
        string[] values = e.Data.Split('|');
        DoSave("save", values.Skip(1).Cast<object>().ToArray());
    ...
    }
...
    public void DoSave(string action, params object[] values) {
    ...
        string value1 = values[0];
    ...
    }
...
```

but instead of receiving an string in value1, value1 is receiving the whole array (string[]) and therefore an invalid casting exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

C# (.NET in general) arrays are covariant. You can simply pass the `string[]` to an `object[]` parameter.

```
DoSave("save", values.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

The code you posted is definitely not the exact code you tested. `Cast<object>` should also work correctly. This line shouldn't compile:

```
string value1 = values[0]; // object -> string, no implicit conversion.
```

Please post the **exact** code causing the problem.

Comment: This is true but the question remains why does this break if you insert a `.Cast<object>()` into the chain?

Comment: AnthonyWJones: It shouldn't break. I think OP is wrong on this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mehrdad but it did not work also.

I've tried your proposal and values[0] is still getting a string[] and because of that I get an exception saying :"can't convert string[] to string.".

When I watch over the values param at the function call It presents: values -> {+object[1]} -> {+string[1]} -> "the real value".

I've tryed:
DoSave("save", values.Skip(1).ToArray());
DoSave("save", (object)values.Skip(1).ToArray());
DoSave("save", values.Skip(1).Cast<object>().ToArray());
DoSave("save", (object)values.Skip(1).Cast<object>().ToArray());
with the same result.

Comment: Ahh and I've tried 
DoSave("save", values[1], values[2]);
That works perfect... but it totally miss the point of the intended implementation.

I really don't know waht going on.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the **exact** code of the `DoSave` method?